# Iterating numerical value and send as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a array with values that I use a forEach to pass values as props to a component. I also want to send a value as props, and increase it by 1 for every iteration. Currently I have tried:

```
this.state = {
 index: 0
}
 let news:any[] = []; //container for other items for the loop
let indx = this.state.index;

    this.state.listItems.forEach((myArrWItems) => {

      indx = +1;
      news.push(<MyComponent


        index = {indx}

        />);
    });
```

However, the value sent in as props is always 1. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `index` state variable is not necessary there. Since you want to create an array from an existing one, you should be using the `map` function, as shown in the official documentation.

This function will give you the `index` of your element right into its callback, as a the second argument.

Your coded can be reduced to a single line :

```
const news = this.state.listItems.map((item, index) => <MyComponent key={index} index={index + 1}/>)
```

Do not forget to set the `key` prop of your component when making an array.

<strike>The `<MyComponent index/>` syntax is the short version of `<MyComponent index={index}/>`</strike>

Comment: Agree map would be better. Was thinking to use functions (forEach has it as well) index parameter, but it starts with 0. Is it possible to make it start from 1?

Comment: Sure, just edited my answer. You can but whatever expression you want in the curly braces of a props definition

Answer (score 1):

You never update your `index` variable, you're just assigning +1 to the `indx` variable which is never mutated. What you need is to update your state and increment your `indx` variable that way and push your value into the array on `setState` callback, but I recommend you to use the current index array element within your `forEach` loop as it is the best way to do what you want to :

```
this.state.listItems.forEach((myListItem, index) => {
      news.push(<MyComponent
        key={index}
        index={index+1}
        />);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Was thinking sbout using the forEach Index function, but it starts at 0, but I want it start from 1. Is it possible?

Comment: Indeed you can simply by adding `index={index+1}` to the given property. 